# insert pandas dataframe into neo4j

Tags: python, pandas, neo4j

I have a pandas DataFrame like - **dataframe**

```
Person1     Person2
933         4139
933         6597069777240
933         10995116284808
```

I want to store them into Neo4j, and I am applying the following code

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", user="neo4j", password="my_password")
tx = graph.begin()
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    tx.evaluate('''
       MATCH (a:person1 {property:$Person1}), (b:person2 {property:$Person2})
       MERGE (a)-[r:R_TYPE]->(b)
       ''', parameters = {'Person1': int(row['Person1']), 'Person2': int(row['Person2'])})
tx.commit()
```

The code is running without errors, but I don't see new nodes created in Neo4j Desktop. I need to deliver a project and don't have much understanding of Neo4j. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure your query is using the correct node labels. Does your DB really have nodes with the labels `person1` and `person2`?
2. Make sure the nodes of interest actually have a property named "property".
3. Make sure the nodes of interest actually store the "property" values as integers.

[UPDATE]

Since you have indicated you do not have any nodes yet, here is an example of Cypher code that will create the nodes and relationships (while avoiding unintended duplicates):

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", user="neo4j", password="my_password")
tx = graph.begin()
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    tx.evaluate('''
       MERGE (a:person1 {property:$Person1})
       MERGE (b:person2 {property:$Person2})
       MERGE (a)-[r:R_TYPE]->(b)
       ''', parameters = {'Person1': int(row['Person1']), 'Person2': int(row['Person2'])})
tx.commit()
```

Comment: I don't have prior created nodes with labels person1/person2. I tried manipulating code which i found on internet,
From my given example DataFrame, my Intention is to create a graph, where each row produces 1 pair of connected node.
933 - 4139, 
933 - 6597069777240, 
933 - 10995116284808, 
So, I want to have 4 nodes with 3 edges. This is an example.
Can you please make changes to my code

Comment: How to set the relationship value also in this code?

Comment: That is actually a subtly complicated question, since we are dealing with [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/). You should read up on `MERGE`, and create a new question if you still have questions.